# Removing element by outerHTML from html collection

Tags: javascript, dom, htmlcollection

I have the following code. I am trying to make an element removed by setting outerHTML to empty(''). I also made few research on html collections and found that it is a live collection

### ref :

- https://idiallo.com/javascript/live-html-collections
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

So all I know is if I change document then the list should change. The code proves this behavior and the loop runs for 4 times despite my initial html collection being of length 9. Now when I replace the outerHTML with innerHTML then the loop for 9 times. So if the list should update with the document being changed, why does not this happen when I replace outerHTML with innerHTML

```
function expTble() {


    let tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table")

    let captions = document.getElementsByTagName("caption")


    if (captions.length > 1) {
        
        console.log(`${tables.length} tables ${captions.length} captions`)

        for (let i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {

            console.log('index : ' + i)
         
            captions[i].outerHTML = ''

        }

        return

    }

    for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        // Do stuffs
        TableExport(tables[i], { bootstrap: false })
    }



}
```

Here is my result

### When using outerHTML

```
9 tables 9 captions 
index : 0 
index : 1 
index : 2 
index : 3 
index : 4
```

### When using innerHTML

```
9 tables 9 captions 
index : 0 
index : 1 
index : 2 
index : 3 
index : 4 
index : 5 
index : 6 
index : 7 
index : 8
```

Comment: You've answered the question yourself: "_it is a live collection_". Removing elements from a live collection during the iteration shortens the collection, and at that point you're jumping over the next member. Setting innerHTML to the empty string doesn't have an affect to the outer HTML of the element, hence it is preserved in the collection (and in the DOM as well). Reduce `i` by one when removing an element, use `querySelectorAll` to get a static collection, or iterate the live collection backwards to fix the issue.

Comment: @Teemu so only the change on the outerHTML(attribute and stuffs) is reflected in the collection?

Comment: Yes, the collection is only a collection of references to the elements specified by the method the collection was created (or by the selector in case of `querySelectorAll`). Either of these are not referring the elements inside of the collected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The live collection updates itself when the element reference by it is changed. In your case the outerHTML changes the element and this updates the collection. But the innerHTML is a deferent piece. It is not something that is referenced by the collection so changes to the child element does not update the html collections.

if you want to remove the element using the same logic, Use While loop and check , if the length is 0, and ref the removing element by 0th index.

```
 if (captions.length > 1) {

        while (captions.length > 0) {
            captions[0].outerHTML = ''
        }

        return

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that you are iterating forwards (0->n) over an array of references while at the same time manipulating the length of it.
When you remove element `i` you are actively shortening the array.
Like in this example:

```
let arr = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
console.log('started');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var removed = arr.splice(i, 0);
    console.log('i:'+i,'Arr:',arr, '(removed ' + i + ')');
}
console.log('ended');
```

this would output the following:

```
started
i:0 Arr: [B,C,D,E,F] (removed A)
i:1 Arr: [B,D,E,F] (removed C)
i:2 Arr: [B,D,F] (removed E)
ended
```

However, if you where to modify your for-loop to iterate in reverse instead you won't get this problem since you always will target an element that hasn't been removed.

```
for (let i = captions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ...
    }

6 tables 6 captions
index : 5
index : 4
index : 3
index : 2
index : 1
index : 0
```

So why does this only happen when you use outerHtml?
The reason to this is that `x.innerHtml = ""` clears the content of the element (`<div>test</div>` -> `<div></div>`), while `x.outerHtml = ""` overwrites the element itself (`<div>test</div>` -> ).

Comment: you have pointed out a very nice logic using the for loop in reverse order thankyou